# ADB: toggle "Adjust wallpaper to Dark mode" button

Tags: adb, settings

EDIT:

Device: Redmi Note 10 Pro - Android 13 - MIUI 14.

I need an ADB command (maybe using the `svc` command?) to toggle off/on the following button:

[image: Adjust wallpaper to Dark mode]

Eg, I am able to toggle the button USB tethering by execute `adb shell svc usb setFunctions rndis`; there is a way to toggle the button for "Adjust wallpaper to Dark mode"?